# How do I extract an impl AsRef<Path> value from a Box<dyn AsRef<Path>>?

Tags: rust, traits

I am using functions from `std::fs`, which take arguments such as `path: impl AsRef<Path>`. I wish to make my own functions polymorphic so they too can take any `impl AsRef<Path>` rather than accepting only `&str`. However, the path-like object in question must be stored inside one of my structs. This means it must be stored as `Box<dyn AsRef<Path>>` to give it a known size. I am struggling to convert this boxed value into anything that can be accepted by the `std::fs` functions.

Consider the following code:

```
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    fn polymorphic(_: impl AsRef<Path>) {}

    let boxed: Box<dyn AsRef<Path>> = Box::new("/foo/bar");
    polymorphic(/*???*/);
}
```

What do I replace the question marks with to allow me to call `polymorphic` with `"/foo/bar"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dereference and re-reference the `Box`:

```
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    fn polymorphic(_: impl AsRef<Path>) {}

    let boxed: Box<dyn AsRef<Path>> = Box::new("/foo/bar");
    polymorphic(&*boxed);
}
```

> This means it must be stored as `Box<dyn AsRef<Path>>`

No it doesn't. The documentation of [`Path`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html) states (emphasis mine):

> This is an unsized type, meaning that it must always be used behind a pointer like `&` or [`Box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html). **For an owned version of this type, see [`PathBuf`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html)**.

```
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

fn polymorphic(_: impl AsRef<Path>) {}

struct Example(PathBuf);

impl Example {
    fn new(path: impl AsRef<Path>) -> Self {
        Self(path.as_ref().to_owned())
    }

    fn example(&self) {
        polymorphic(&self.0)
    }
}
```

I would actually use `Into<PathBuf>` myself, as this allows someone to give me ownership of something they no longer need:

```
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

fn polymorphic(_: impl AsRef<Path>) {}

struct Example(PathBuf);

impl Example {
    fn new(path: impl Into<PathBuf>) -> Self {
        Self(path.into())
    }

    fn example(&self) {
        polymorphic(&self.0)
    }
}
```